# Importance of WGS84 realization for centimeter-level accurate UTM transformation

Tags: gps, wgs84, utm

I am working with a high-end GNSS receiver connected to an RTK correction data service. I need to measure the position of a ground point with centimeter-level (2-5cm) accuracy. The GNSS receiver provides the data with respect to the WGS84 datum (as longitude, latitude), which I want to convert to UTM coordinates in the 30N zone (as northing, easting).

I read here https://confluence.qps.nl/qinsy/latest/en/world-geodetic-system-1984-wgs84-182618391.html
that WGS84 has multiple realizations, and I wonder if this has to be taken into account to obtain a centimeter-level accurate position of the point in UTM.

More precisely, my questions are:

1. Are the outputs of my GNSS receiver automatically referring to the latest WGS84 realization (G1762), or do I have to ask the sensor manufacturer which realization is being used?
2. **Does the transformation from WGS84 to UTM depend on the WGS84 realization?** Or is the transformation the same for all realizations and I need to specify the realization used when reporting the ground point's UTM position? If the transformation depends on the realization, how can I specify it e.g. in pyproj or what is an appropriate program to use?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

Once you apply RTK corrections the corrected position is supplied in reference frame used by the RTK base station so check what your correction supplier uses.

I can't comment on conversion of Lat / Long to UTM since I use Lat / Long myself.